# Manually deleting val from context map using Gorilla middleware

Tags: go, gorilla, context-tracing, golang-context

Do I need to do this:

```
  r.Use(func(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
      muxctx.Set(r, "req-res-ctx", &mw.Ctx{
        Log: vbl.Stdout.Child(&map[string]interface{}{}),
      })
      defer func() {   
        muxctx.Delete(r, "req-res-ctx") // <-------------------- HERE
      }()
      next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
  })
```

or does the context magically auto-delete the entry? I would think that I would also need to do this:

```
      defer func() {   
        muxctx.Delete(r) // delete ref to request too?
      }()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like we should use muxctx.Clear(r) like so:

```
  r.Use(func(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
      muxctx.Set(r, "req-res-ctx", &mw.Ctx{
        Log: vbl.Stdout.Child(&map[string]interface{}{}),
      })
      defer func() {
        muxctx.Delete(r, "req-res-ctx")
        muxctx.Clear(r)  // <---------------HERE
      }()
      next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
  })
```

I also read that we should use the `ctx := r.Context()` but this API seems confusing and not sure if it's an improvement.